# Javascript - Stop scrolling on certain links

Tags: javascript, scroll

For example,

```
<a href="#foo">Foo</a>
<a href="#bar">Bar</a>

 ...

<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Is there a way to selectively stop scrolling for certain elements?

In the example, above, what if I want the browser to not scroll to the #bar element if the anchor that has `href="#bar" is clicked?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use a click handler that returns `false`, which prevents the default click action.

```
<a href="#bar" onclick="return false;">Bar</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, what you are looking for is how to **prevent browser default behaviour**

example (using jQuery)

```
$('a').on('click', function(event){
    if($(this).attr('href') == '#bar'){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of thr ways that I can suggest is to remove the href attribute in some specific circumstances. But removing href attribute may result in the anchor appear to be not clickable anymore...

If you want your anchor to still appear to be clickable:

'$("a").removeAttr("href").css("cursor","pointer");'

You may specify ids for specific anchor elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class or id to links that you don't want to scroll, you can then add an event listener to those links and prevent the default action on click.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#foo">Foo</a>
<a href="#bar" class="blockedLink">Bar</a>

...

<h2 id="foo">Foo</h2>
<h2 id="bar">Bar</h2>
```

**Javascript**

```
var blockedLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('blockedLink');

for (var i = 0; i < blockedLinks.length; i++) {
    blockedLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3prT5/)**